# vb.Net - How do you trim a text string?

Tags: vb.net

This is the string of text I am trying to cut down... [ Is an output from CMD ]

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586] (c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation.
>   All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\TEST!\TEST!\bin\Debug> cd C:\FTV\ADB
>
> C:\FTV\ADB>adb devices List of devices attached 
>   0715f7b5c1791d38  device
>
> C:\FTV\ADB>Exit

and i just want to get `0715f7b5c1791d38    device` out of all that.

Any help is extremely appreciated!

Comment: You need to explain how the code is supposed to know what part of the string it is you want. Is it the word "device" and the word that precedes it? is it the last two words on the second last line? is it the 'word' "0715f7b5c1791d38"  and the word that follows it? Something else?

Answer (score 3):

You can get that out with `Regex`... You can see it here: https://regex101.com/r/sM5hU4/1

```
 attached (.*?) device
```

**Breakdown of the above**

- 1st caturing group is (.*?) which matches any character besides newline...
- The quantifier (*?) between zero and unlimited times only expanding as need (lazy).

Note: if this could exist more than once in the string this would have to be altered as it would need to capture groups...

Answer (score -1):

Codexer answered while I was writing this, His answer explains the regex and this is how to use it:

```
    MsgBox(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match("attached 0715f7b5c1791d38 device", "attached (.*?) device").Groups(1).Value)
```

change the "`attached 0715f7b5c1791d38 device`" to the variable with your string.

And the `attached (.*?) device` is the regex.

`.Groups(0)` will be the complete string

`.Groups(1)` will be first matching group (you can group by placing your the group you want into brackets)

And to save on writing you can add `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions` to the top of the class, then you can just use `regex.match(expression, regex_string)` instead of `System.Text.RegularExpressions`